# Best way to get a return tag from a sql SELECT command

Tags: sql, sqlite

I making a virtual assistant client for my University project and there is a slight problem in getting a tag return based on match string.
The system works like this:
1. The user speech input is converted into a string.
2. The string is then matched to column in table.
3. The matching column returns its id which then return two tags from another table.

The problem is for calling someone, how should I go around it?
I mean, the user will say something like this: "Call Arya", here I can't have predefined command for each person so I have to use "MATCH" or "LIKE" selectors in SQL.
But then if I use these selectors then it will return me the tag for say opening facebook app even if I just "facebook", as the commands for facebook will be "open facebook" or "run facebook".

So how to work around it. Please help.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  I cannot discern if you are trying to build a sql statement, or build keywords for your voice control.  Please post the code you are having trouble with and what the expected output should be.

Comment: I am sorry about that, I want to build a SQL statement so that I can get tags for calling a person by doing a partial search on keywords but I want it so that it does not return me a tag to run an app just when I say that app's name, that I don't want to run the app when the user just says "facebook" or even "open" would return some tags.
Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: It makes sense, but its far to broad to be answered effectively.  I have no basis for what you've done or what your skill level is to do it.Usually the way this is handled is via keywords.  A keyword (like "call") triggers an app (or thread) to run Sounds to me like you need to build a list of words to exclude, then search on everything else.  You might be interested in [one of my previous answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22510450/speech-recognition-with-free-speech/22512330#22512330)

Comment: I am a beginner, as a programmer, what I inferred is, I can have a separate filters built right in java that would tend specifically to call function as its a special case and for everything else I can have that database approach. The reason I am don't want to put all the commands in java is that I think its not a good solution as it doesn't follow DRYness. I hope I am right.

Comment: I have no idea if the implementation as you have described follows anything, because its not implemented.  I suggest you write something.  If you have a bug, post it here.  If you want to know if you can do it better, check out [codereview.se].

Comment: Sure once I have implemented everything I will post the code @CodeReview 
Thanks for the suggestion